# Cepstrum Calculation of Rational Function H(z)

Tags: discrete-signals, fourier-transform, dft, z-transform, cepstral-analysis

I am trying to solve my first problems at cepstrum calculation. I want to calculate the complex cepstrum $\hat{h}[n]$ of a signal $h[n]$ with Z-Transform:
$$H(z)=\frac{(1-0.5z^{-1})(1+4z^{-2})}{(1-0.64z^{-2})}$$
I know that $\hat{H}[z]=\log(H(z))$ and $\hat{h}[n]=\frac{1}{2π}\int_{-π}^{π}\log[H(e^{jω})]e^{jωn}dω$

Which is the easiest way to approach this?

I started by applying $\log()$ to H(z) which gave me:
$$\log(H(z))=\log(1-0.5z^{-1})+\log(1+4z^{-2})-\log(1-0.64z^{-2})\Rightarrow $$
$$\log(H(z))=\log(1-0.5z^{-1})+\log(4(z^{-2}+\frac{1}{4}))-\log((1-0.8z^{-1})(1+0.8z^{-1}))\Rightarrow$$
$$\log(H(z))=\log(1-0.5z^{-1})+\log(4(z^{-1}+\frac{j}{2})(z^{-1}-\frac{j}{2}))-\log((1-0.8z^{-1})(1+0.8z^{-1}))\Rightarrow$$
$$\log(H(z))=\log(1-0.5z^{-1})+\log(4)+\log(z^{-1}+\frac{j}{2})+\log(z^{-1}-\frac{j}{2}))-\log(1-0.8z^{-1})-\log(1+0.8z^{-1})$$

Is this apporach right? If so, how do I go on? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this an exercise from a book?

Comment: @MattL. No it's not from a book. Is my approach right? I also consider making use of the power series: $$\log(1-az^{-1})=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a^{n}}{n}z^{-n}$$ but not every term is in such a form.

Comment: I asked because I think that you have to remove a linear phase term in order to compute the complex cepstrum. If it had been from a book I would have been surprised at the necessity to discover that fact. I'll write up an answer as soon as I have the time to do so.

Comment: I am not used to computing complex cepstrums. I am now trying to solve my first problems. So, I am not sure about my approach. I just tried to use the definition and make use of some properties of the log() function. However, I am finding difficulty calculating the inverse Z -transform of the expression I end up to so that  I get the complex cepstrum $\hat{h}[n]$. Thanks a lot for the response. I am looking forward for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're looking for a series representation

$$\log H(z)=C(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}c[n]z^{-n}\tag{1}$$

which converges in an annular region $r_1<|z|<r_2$ with $0<r_1<1<r_2$.

Note that the poles as well as the zeros of $H(z)$ lead to singularities of $C(z)$. All poles and zeros of $H(z)$ *inside* the unit circle contribute to the right-sided part of $c[n]$, whereas the poles and zeros of $H(z)$ *outside* the unit circle contribute to the left-sided part of $c[n]$. Consequently, a minimum-phase transfer function $H(z)$ has a right-sided cepstrum.

The given function $H(z)$ has all its poles inside the unit circle ($z^{\infty}_{1,2}=\pm 0.8$, $z^{\infty}_{3}=0$), one of its zeros is inside the unit circle ($z^{0}_{1}=0.5$), and two zeros are outside the unit circle ($z^{0}_{2,3}=\pm 2j$). Consequently, its complex cepstrum $c[n]$ is a two-sided sequence.

In order to find the sequence $c[n]$ we make use of the well-known [Mercator series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_series):

$$\log(1-z)=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n},\qquad |z|<1\tag{2}$$

From $(2)$ it is clear that terms of the form

$$\log(1-az^{-1})=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a^n}{n}z^{-n},\qquad |z|>|a|\tag{3}$$

contribute to the right-sided part of $c[n]$, whereas terms of the form

$$\log(1-bz)=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{b^n}{n}z^{n}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1}\frac{b^{-n}}{n}z^{-n},\qquad |z|<\frac{1}{|b|}\tag{4}$$

contribute to the left-sided part of $c[n]$. Note the argument can be easily generalized to higher powers of $z$ on the left-hand sides of $(3)$ and $(4)$.

The term $(1+4z^{-2})$ in the numerator of the given function $H(z)$ corresponds to two zeros outside the unit circle, and, consequently, it contributes to the left-sided part of $c[n]$. Hence, according to $(4)$, it must be rewritten in terms of positive powers of $z$:

$$(1+4z^{-2})=4z^{-2}(1+0.25z^2)\tag{5}$$

We have

$$H(z)=z^{-2}\frac{4(1-0.5z^{-1})(1+0.25z^2)}{(1-0.64z^{-2})}=z^{-2}\tilde{H}(z)\tag{6}$$

I *think* that due to the linear-phase term $z^{-2}$ in $(6)$ we actually cannot compute the complex cepstrum of $H(z)$, but we *can* compute the complex cepstrum of $\tilde{H}(z)$, which is just a shifted version of the original function $H(z)$.

From $(6)$ we obtain

$$\log \tilde{H}(z)=\log(4)+\log(1-0.5z^{-1})+\log(1+0.25z^{2})-\log(1-0.64z^{-2})\tag{7}$$

Using $(3)$ and $(4)$ we get

$$\log \tilde{H}(z)=\log(4)-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(0.5)^n}{n}z^{-n}+\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1}\frac{(-0.25)^{-n}}{n}z^{-2n}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(0.64)^n}{n}z^{-2n}\tag{8}$$

which is equivalent to

$$\log \tilde{H}(z)=\log(4)-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(0.5)^n}{n}z^{-n}+\sum_{n=-\infty\\n\textrm{ even}}^{-1}\frac{2(-0.5)^{-n}}{n}z^{-n}+\sum_{n=1\\n\textrm{ even}}^{\infty}\frac{2(0.8)^n}{n}z^{-n}\tag{9}$$

The region of convergence of the series representation $(9)$ is $0.8<|z|<2$, which includes the unit circle, as required by the definition of the complex cepstrum.

From $(9)$ we can directly write down the complex cepstrum of $\tilde{H}(z)$:

$$\tilde{c}[n]=\begin{cases}\log(4),&n=0\\
\frac{1}{n}\left[2(0.8)^n-(0.5)^n\right],&n>0 \land n\textrm{ even}\\-\frac{1}{n}(0.5)^n,&n>0 \land n\textrm{ odd}\\\frac{2}{n}(-0.5)^{-n},&n<0 \land n\textrm{ even}\\0,&n<0\land n \textrm{ odd}\end{cases}\tag{10}$$

Comment: Great explanation!If I wanted to calculate the real cepstrum $c[n]$ as well, should I use the following property? :  $$c[n]=\frac{\tilde{c}[n]+\tilde{c}[-n]}{2} $$

Comment: @MJ13: Yes, that should work.

Comment: The given transfer function doesn't have a pole: $z^{\infty}_{3}=0$ , right?

Comment: @MJ13: It does!

Comment: The denominator of my transfer fucntion is : $1-0.64z^{-2}$ . So it has two poles which are: $z^{\infty}_{1,2}=\pm 0.8$. Am I wrong?

Comment: @MJ13: No, you're not wrong, it has those two poles (as I've written in my answer), but you seem to be missing the one at $z=0$. If you don't see it, multiply numerator and denominator by $z^3$, that should make it more obvious.

Comment: Oh yeah!I missed that. One more question. What's exactly the definition of the "contribution to the left-sided" or the "contribution to the right-sided part of $c[n]$"?

Comment: @MJ13: A right-sided sequence starts at some finite index (often $n=0$), and extends to $n\to\infty$. Same (but opposite) for a left-sided sequence.

Comment: If I would like to separate the fucntion $H(z)$ to a minimum phase trasnfer function $H_1(z)$ and a FIR of a generalized linear phase $H_l(z)$ , so that : $H(z) = H_1(z) \cdot H_l(z)$  would it be correct to say that $$H_1(z) = \frac{1-0.5z^{-1}}{1-0.64z^{-2}}$$ and  $$H_l(z) = 1 + 4z^{-2}$$ ??

Comment: @MJ13: Yes, that's an option. $H_1(z)$ has all its poles and zeros inside the unit circle, so it's indeed minimum-phase. And the other filter is FIR but not (generalized) linear phase.

Comment: @ Matt L. : Is there a way we could continue this discussion to chat so that I could ask you something without spamming here?

Comment: I just don't see any option about the chat here in the comment section. Is something like that possible or I should ask a new question?

Comment: @MJ13: It's probably best to ask a new question.

Comment: Think I managed to solve the problem by myself. If not, I will ask a new question. Thanks for the help and the advice!

Comment: I think there is a sign mistake here: $$\log(1+0.25z^{-2})=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1}\frac{(-0.25)^{-n}}{n}z^{-2n}$$

Comment: @MJ13: Yes, thanks. Fixed.